# Skip first key while dumping JSON to the file

Tags: python, json

For examle, this is JSON file

```
{
    "0": {
        "xxx": "123",
        "aaa": "456"
    },
    "1": {
        "xxx": "123",
        "aaa": "456"
    },
    "2": {
        "xxx": "123",
        "aaa": "56775"
    }.....

}
```

And I need to skip first  keys to make it like this:

```
{
    "xxx": "123",
    "aaa": "456"
}
{
    "xxx": "123",
    "aaa": "456"
}
{
    "xxx": "123",
    "aaa": "56775"
}.....
```

My assumption is that is should be something like this:

```
for p in responseMain:
            skipPLU = responseMain[p]
            ......
```

This is how I writing to the file:

```
with open('TEST.json', "w+") as op:
        json.dump(responseMain,op)
```

Comment: Your desired output can be done, but it is not valid JSON.

Comment: @pault I know it's not a valid JSON, made for BigQuery

Comment: Do you want a JSON array like `[{"xxx": "123", "aaa":"456"}, ...]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

`responseMain.values()`

to get the list of dict values - without keys:

> `dict_values([{'xxx': '123', 'aaa': '456'}, {'xxx': '123', 'aaa': '56775'}, {'xxx': '123', 'aaa': '456'}])`

or:

`list(responseMain.values())`

> ```
> [{'aaa': '456', 'xxx': '123'},
>  {'aaa': '56775', 'xxx': '123'},
>  {'aaa': '456', 'xxx': '123'}]
> ```

---

Your desired JSON is not valid, you should wrap it into a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want each object to be a separate JSON in the file, not part of a JSON array, you need to write them each separately.

```
import json
with open('TEST.json', "w+") as op:
    for item in responseMain.values():
        json.dump(item, op)
```